# Can you polarise a lens by rubbing it with your finger?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, polarization, lenses

Here's a phenomenon that you all might have come across . I took two photos on my phone, keeping it in landscape mode. I noticed that the light rays get polarised, or rather "smudged" when I rubbed the camera lens with my finger.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I noticed that the direction of the smudge was perpendicular to the direction in which the lens was rubbed.

I wonder why I spent so much money to buy glasses with a polarizing coat, when I could have just used my finger!

How can you explain the "polarisation"?

Comment: What makes you think that's polarisation? Try taking a few photos with a genuine polarising filter in front of your smudged lens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the light is polarized here. You do not get smearing when viewing/photographing through a polarization filter.

Rather, tiny traces of fat your finger leaves on the lens cause this smearing. It will be indeed perpendicular to the direction in which the lens was rubbed, because the fat will be distributed less uniformly in the perpendicular direction.